# SivlerStripe field to render Javascript tags/ code

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am developing a SilverStripe project. In my project, I am trying to create a custom content block where admin can enter the Javascript code to be rendered on the front-end.

I have two field

```
private static $db = [
        'Script' => 'Text',
        'Content' => 'HTMLText',
    ];
```

(Note the Script field).

In the template, I render the variables like this.

```
$Script
$Content
```

Then in the Script textarea field, I entered the following content

```
<script>alert("I am the Script")</script>
```

When I go to the front-end page after publishing, I see this instead.

[image]

How can I create a field where I can enter Javascript code in the SilverStripe?

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure that you can use the raw modifier

```
$Script.RAW
```